# Java/Android - Validate String JSON against String schema

Tags: java, android, json, jsonschema

I am having trouble finding the most simple way to validate a JSON String against a given JSON-schema String (for reference, this is in Java, running in an Android app).

Ideally, I'd like to just pass in a JSON String and a JSON-schema String, and it returns a boolean as to whether it passes the validation.  Through searching, I have found the following 2 promising libraries for accomplishing this:

http://jsontools.berlios.de/

https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator

However, the first one seems fairly outdated with poor support.  I implemented the library into my project, and even with their JavaDocs, I was unable to tell how to properly build a "Validator" object for validation.

Similar story with the 2nd one, which seems to be up-to-date with good test code.  However, for what I want to do, which is very simple, it seems to be a bit daunting and confusing as to how to specifically accomplish what I want (even after looking at the [ValidateServlet.java](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/jsonschema/servlets/ValidateServlet.java) file).

Curious if anyone has any other suggestions on a good way to accomplish this (from what it seems), simple task that need, or if I perhaps need to stick with the 2nd option from above?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Author of json-schema-validator here... Didn't you see in the README that there was a link to code samples? ;)

Comment: Hi there, and thank you for your great library!  Yes indeed, I did see the code samples and actually mentioned it in my post with an embedded link (the ValidateServlet.java file).  Thanks again for this library! Great stuff :)

Comment: I wasn't talking about this sample: I was talking about `com.github.fge.jsonschema.examples` in the javadoc ;) BTW, 1.6.0 is out.

Comment: Ah I did not notice that then!  Thanks for the heads up on that, as well as the new version. :)

Comment: @fge I cannot seem to get this working on Android targeting api 23

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is essentially what the Servlet you linked to does, so it may not be a one-liner but it still is expressive.

`useV4` and `useId` as specified on the servlet, are for specifying validations option for `Default to draft v4` and `Use id for addressing`.

You can see it online: http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/

```
public boolean validate(String jsonData, String jsonSchema, boolean useV4, boolean useId) throws Exception {
   // create the Json nodes for schema and data
   JsonNode schemaNode = JsonLoader.fromString(jsonSchema); // throws JsonProcessingException if error
   JsonNode data = JsonLoader.fromString(jsonData);         // same here

   JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactories.withOptions(useV4, useId);
   // load the schema and validate
   JsonSchema schema = factory.fromSchema(schemaNode);
   ValidationReport report = schema.validate(data);

   return report.isSuccess();
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!  I guess I probably just needed a nudge in the right direction on the proper way of using this library.  Really appreciate it!

Comment: Note that the implementation detects `$schema` and defaults to draft v3. In most cases, you just use `JsonSchemaFactory.defaultFactory()`.

Answer (score 14):

A grateful thank you to Douglas Crockford and Francis Galiegue for writing the java-based json schema processor!  And the on-line tester at http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/index.jsp is awesome! I really like the helpful error messages (I only found one example in which they failed), though line and column and/or context would be even better (right now, you only get line and column information during JSON format errors (courtesy of Jackson). Finally, I'd like to thank Michael Droettboom for his *great* tutorial (even if he only covered Python, Ruby, and C while conspicuously ignoring the best language of all :-)).

For those who missed it (like I did at first), there are examples are at github.com/fge/json-schema-processor-examples.  While these examples are very impressive, they are not the simple json validation examples that were originally requested (and that I too was looking for).  The simple examples are at github.com/fge/json-schema-validator/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/jsonschema/examples/Example1.java

Alex's code above did not work for me, but was very helpful; my pom is pulling the latest stable release, version 2.0.1 with the following dependency inserted in my maven pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then the following java code works fine for me:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.exceptions.ProcessingException;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchema;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.report.ProcessingMessage;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.report.ProcessingReport;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.util.JsonLoader;


public class JsonValidationExample  
{

public boolean validate(String jsonData, String jsonSchema) {
    ProcessingReport report = null;
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        System.out.println("Applying schema: @<@<"+jsonSchema+">@>@ to data: #<#<"+jsonData+">#>#");
        JsonNode schemaNode = JsonLoader.fromString(jsonSchema);
        JsonNode data = JsonLoader.fromString(jsonData);         
        JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault(); 
        JsonSchema schema = factory.getJsonSchema(schemaNode);
        report = schema.validate(data);
    } catch (JsonParseException jpex) {
        System.out.println("Error. Something went wrong trying to parse json data: #<#<"+jsonData+
                ">#># or json schema: @<@<"+jsonSchema+">@>@. Are the double quotes included? "+jpex.getMessage());
        //jpex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProcessingException pex) {  
        System.out.println("Error. Something went wrong trying to process json data: #<#<"+jsonData+
                ">#># with json schema: @<@<"+jsonSchema+">@>@ "+pex.getMessage());
        //pex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error. Something went wrong trying to read json data: #<#<"+jsonData+
                ">#># or json schema: @<@<"+jsonSchema+">@>@");
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (report != null) {
        Iterator<ProcessingMessage> iter = report.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            ProcessingMessage pm = iter.next();
            System.out.println("Processing Message: "+pm.getMessage());
        }
        result = report.isSuccess();
    }
    System.out.println(" Result=" +result);
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println( "Starting Json Validation." );
    JsonValidationExample app = new JsonValidationExample();
    String jsonData = "\"Redemption\"";
    String jsonSchema = "{ \"type\": \"string\", \"minLength\": 2, \"maxLength\": 11}";
    app.validate(jsonData, jsonSchema);
    jsonData = "Agony";  // Quotes not included
    app.validate(jsonData, jsonSchema);
    jsonData = "42";
    app.validate(jsonData, jsonSchema);
    jsonData = "\"A\"";
    app.validate(jsonData, jsonSchema);
    jsonData = "\"The pity of Bilbo may rule the fate of many.\"";
    app.validate(jsonData, jsonSchema);
}

}
```

My result from the above code is:

```
Starting Json Validation.
Applying schema: @<@<{ "type": "string", "minLength": 2, "maxLength": 11}>@>@ to data: #<#<"Redemption">#>#
 Result=true
Applying schema: @<@<{ "type": "string", "minLength": 2, "maxLength": 11}>@>@ to data: #<#<Agony>#>#
Error. Something went wrong trying to parse json data: #<#<Agony>#># or json schema: @<@<{ "type": "string", "minLength": 2, "maxLength": 11}>@>@. Are the double quotes included?
 Result=false
Applying schema: @<@<{ "type": "string", "minLength": 2, "maxLength": 11}>@>@ to data: #<#<42>#>#
Processing Message: instance type does not match any allowed primitive type
 Result=false
Applying schema: @<@<{ "type": "string", "minLength": 2, "maxLength": 11}>@>@ to data: #<#<"A">#>#
Processing Message: string is too short
 Result=false
Applying schema: @<@<{ "type": "string", "minLength": 2, "maxLength": 11}>@>@ to data: #<#<"The pity of Bilbo may rule the fate of many.">#>#
Processing Message: string is too long
 Result=false
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Nice example Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

@Alex's answer worked for me on Android but required me to Multi-dex and add:

```
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/ASL-2.0.txt'
        pickFirst 'draftv4/schema'
        pickFirst 'draftv3/schema'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LGPL-3.0.txt'
    }
```

to my `build.gradle`

Comment: Thanks! Note: `pickFirst` is crucial here. Do not use `exclude`: although it makes compilation pass, it causes other issues because the code relies on the presence of the schema files.