# No class found Exception while validating Json with JsonSchema

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am new to Java.

I am trying to validate a Json with JsonSchema. I have referred [Java/Android - Validate String JSON against String schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511468/java-android-validate-string-json-against-string-schema).. I have tried with #Tihamer code and I am getting a JsonParserException which I have not used it.

Below is my code

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.report.ProcessingMessage;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.report.ProcessingReport;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchema;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory;

public class JsonValidation {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JsonValidation jv = new JsonValidation();
        String jsonData = "{\"dispatcherMode\":\"standard\",\"noOfdispatcher\":\"3\",\"dispatcherInfo\":[{\"dispatcher\":\"Dispatcher 0 = 156.95.53.243:6108<--current\"},{\"dispatcher\":\"Dispatcher 1 = 156.95.53.220:6108\"},{\"dispatcher\":\"Dispatcher 2 = 172.26.41.113:6108\"}],\"noOfAuthServer\":\"3\",\"connected\":\"3\",\"authorizationInfo\":[{\"authServer\":\"authserver 0 = 172.26.41.114:6115(connected)<--current\",\"requests\":\"1503\",\"failures\":\"1\",\"queued\":\"0\",\"delay\":\"10225\"},{\"authServer\":\"authserver 1 = 156.95.53.220:6115(connected)\",\"requests\":\"10745\",\"failures\":\"0\",\"queued\":\"0\",\"delay\":\"5762\"},{\"authServer\":\"authserver 2 = 172.26.41.113:6115(connected)\",\"requests\":\"12545\",\"failures\":\"1\",\"queued\":\"0\",\"delay\":\"9756\"}],\"noOfCache\":\"2\",\"cacheInfo\":[{\"cacheNumber\":\"cache 0\",\"request\":\"0\",\"hits\":\"0\",\"entries\":\"0\",\"size\":\"10000\",\"ttl\":\"600sec\"},{\"cacheNumber\":\"cache 1\",\"request\":\"1\",\"hits\":\"1\",\"entries\":\"1\",\"size\":\"12000\",\"ttl\":\"300sec\"}]}";
        String jsonSchema = "{\"type\": \"object\",\"properties\": {\"dispatcherMode\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"noOfdispatcher\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"dispatcherInfo\": {\"type\": \"array\",\"items\": [{\"type\": \"object\",\"properties\": {\"dispatcher\": {\"type\": \"string\"}}},{\"type\": \"object\",\"properties\": {\"dispatcher\": {\"type\": \"string\"}}},{\"type\": \"object\",\"properties\": {\"dispatcher\": {\"type\": \"string\"}}}]},\"noOfAuthServer\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"connected\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"authorizationInfo\": {\"type\": \"array\",\"items\": [{\"type\": \"object\",\"properties\": {\"authServer\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"requests\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"failures\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"queued\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"delay\": {\"type\": \"string\"}}},{\"type\": \"object\",\"properties\": {\"authServer\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"requests\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"failures\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"queued\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"delay\": {\"type\": \"string\"}}},{\"type\": \"object\",\"properties\": {\"authServer\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"requests\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"failures\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"queued\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"delay\": {\"type\": \"string\"}}}]},\"noOfCache\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"cacheInfo\": {\"type\": \"array\",\"items\": [{\"type\": \"object\",\"properties\": {\"cacheNumber\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"request\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"hits\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"entries\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"size\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"ttl\": {\"type\": \"string\"}}},{\"type\": \"object\",\"properties\": {\"cacheNumber\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"request\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"hits\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"entries\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"size\": {\"type\": \"string\"},\"ttl\": {\"type\": \"string\"}}}]}},\"required\": [\"dispatcherMode\",\"noOfdispatcher\",\"dispatcherInfo\",\"noOfAuthServer\",\"connected\",\"authorizationInfo\",\"noOfCache\",\"cacheInfo\"]}";
        jv.validation(jsonData, jsonSchema);
    }


    public boolean validation(String  jsonData, String jsonSchema)
    {
        ProcessingReport report = null;
        boolean result = false;
        try{
            JsonNode schemaNode = JsonLoader.fromString(jsonSchema);
            JsonNode dataNode = JsonLoader.fromString(jsonData);
            JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
            JsonSchema schema = factory.getJsonSchema(schemaNode);
            report = schema.validate(dataNode);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (report != null) {
            Iterator<ProcessingMessage> iter = report.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                ProcessingMessage pm = iter.next();
                System.out.println("Processing Message: "+pm.getMessage());
            }
            result = report.isSuccess();
        }
        System.out.println(" Result=" +result);
        return result;
    }

}
```

and below is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParseException
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader.<clinit>(JsonLoader.java:50)
    at JsonValidation.validation(JsonValidation.java:25)
    at JsonValidation.main(JsonValidation.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

I solved the previous error but now I am getting error like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:537)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:448)
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JacksonUtils.newMapper(JacksonUtils.java:155)
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JacksonUtils.<clinit>(JacksonUtils.java:55)
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JsonNodeReader.<init>(JsonNodeReader.java:82)
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader.<clinit>(JsonLoader.java:50)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.examples.Utils.loadResource(Utils.java:53)
    at JsonValidateTest.main(JsonValidateTest.java:19)
```

I have not used the objectMapper class but I am getting exception.

Comment: check my update for second error

Comment: @VedantKekan mine is not the maven project.. so wer can i add the dependency??

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: @VedantKekan Thank you.. it got resolved, only thing missing was jar i added all the jars and go the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following part in your stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

It clearly suggests that the `error` is caused by a class `JsonParseException` of the package `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` which the JVM tried to load but could not find it as it is not in your classpath.

Just add the `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` jar file in your classpath.

Comment: Thank you @thegauravmahawar.. your answer helped me to solve that error.

Comment: can you help me with the other error which i mentioned in the same question??

Answer (score 0):

Add jackson-annotations.jar
Download it from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations)

If maven project, add this dependancy.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

PS:
Whenever you get classnotfound, consider you need to make that class available

> **JUST FYI**:public class ClassNotFoundException
>   extends ReflectiveOperationException
>
> Thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its string name using:

- The forName method in class Class.
- The findSystemClass method in class ClassLoader .
- The loadClass method in class ClassLoader.
  but no definition for the class with the specified name could be found.

From [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html)

For second error: Add This (Replace version)
Download jar [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core) and add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thank you... i downloaded the jar file and got rid of this error.. Thank you for your help