# Dynamically validating a JSON response format

Tags: java, http, jackson

Typically if I wanted to validate a JSON response I would create DTOs and use a library to parse the response into a DTO class. If the parse fails then I can confirm the format of the response body is invalid.

The problem is I want to dynamically configure API endpoints to hit and dynamically configure a way to validate the format of the JSON response. Is there a good way to accomplish this?

`config.json`

```
{
  {
    "url": "http://www.example.com/api/v1/test1",
    "response": (expected Dto1)
  },
  {
    "url": "http://www.example.com/api/v1/test2",
    "response": (expected Dto2)
  }
}
```

Comment: Found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511468/java-android-validate-string-json-against-string-schema